# Are there $5$ non-cyclic groups of order $2^n$ with an element of order $2^{n-1}\ $?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

There are $5$ non-cyclic groups of order $128$ with an element of order $64$,
namely

$$C64 \times C2\ ,\ C64 : C2\ ,\ D128\ ,\ QD128\ ,\ Q128$$

Similar, there are $5$ non-cyclic groups of order $256$ with an element of order $128$, namely

$$C128\times C2\ ,\ C128:C2\ ,\ D256\ ,\ QD256\ ,\ Q256$$

> Are there exactly $5$ non-cyclic groups of order $2^n $ with an element of order $2^{n-1}$ for every $n\ge 7$ , and are the groups analogue to the groups listed above ?
>
> I also counted the groups of order $128$ with an element of order $32$, but no element with a larger order, and similar the groups of order $256$ with an element of order $64$ , but no element with a larger order. I got $27$ in both cases. Is this a coincide, or does it hold for every $2^n$ with $n\ge 7$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct number. The finite $p$-groups with a cyclic subgroup of index $p$ have been completely classified (see for example Berkovich's book).

Comment: How many such groups do we have for other primes $p$, also $5$ (for sufficiently large group order ) ?

Comment: No, only two for odd primes (i.e. a unique non-abelian one).

Comment: Do you know the answer to my second question ?

Comment: I doubt much can be said in the other cases, though I didn't check if Berkovich might have something about it.